# Changing chain specification

Tags: private-blockchain, parity, hardforks

We have a private network with 10 nodes actually. It's been working for a couple months now.

When we did it, we set up some parameters in the chain specification that are now too small for the growth we've been having.

So we need to update the chain specification, to increase gasLimit and, essentially, to allow a lot more transactions per block.

I know that to change the chain genesis file implies a hard fork, but, is there a way to do a this AND keep the data already in the chain?

How is it done when a hard fork is made in the mainnet?

Even if this is not possible, what parameters do I have to increase to allow more transactions per block?

Our values are, right now:

```
"gasLimitBoundDivisor": "0x400",
"maximumExtraDataSize": "0xF4240",
"minGasLimit": "0x1388",
"difficulty": "0x20000",
"gasLimit": "0x5B8D80"
```

Thanks!